# Enable/Disable one script from another one on specific game object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I made a script to cast a ray and see whether the mouse cursor is looking at an object or not, and another script will then use that to turn on/off and outline script on said object. The first script is working, the ray casting one, but I can't figure out how to properly disable/enable the outline script from that one. Right now, the outline is always on. So basically, how do I fix it so its only on when highlighted? (also I'm new to stackoverflow so if the formatting is weird thats why)

Code for raycast:

```
public static string selectedObject;
public string internalObject;
public RaycastHit theObject;
public LayerMask layerMask;
public bool rayObjectHit;

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    // Script for highlighting object

    
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out theObject, layerMask))
        {
            selectedObject = theObject.transform.gameObject.name;
            internalObject = theObject.transform.gameObject.name;
        }
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out theObject, layerMask) == false)
    {
        selectedObject = GameObject.Find("none").name;
    }
        // Script for clicking on object
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out theObject, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.Log(theObject.transform.gameObject.name);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Code for Outline:

```
{
public GameObject selectedObject;
public static string objectSelected;
public bool lookingAtObject = false;
public bool outlineOn;
public static string outlinedObject;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    selectedObject = GameObject.Find("none");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
        selectedObject = GameObject.Find(CastingToObject.selectedObject);
        lookingAtObject = true;
    if (selectedObject = GameObject.Find("none"))
    {
        lookingAtObject = false;
    }    
    
            
   
    if (lookingAtObject == true)
    {
        selectedObject.GetComponent<GameObject>();
        while (lookingAtObject == true)
        {
            outlineOn = true;
            selectedObject.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    if (lookingAtObject == false)
    {
            outlineOn = false;
            selectedObject.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the Raycast twice! You can simply use `else` which means there as no hit.

I would do something like

```
// Store the current selected outline reference
Outline currentSelected;

private void Update ()
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    // Do they Raycast only ONCE!
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, layerMask))
    {
        // Are we hitting a new object?
        if(!currentSelected || currentSelected.gameObject != hit.gameObject)
        {
            // Was there already something selected?
            // And if so is it a different object?
            if(currentSelected && currentSelected.gameObject != hit.gameObject)
            {
                currentSelected.enabled = false;
            }

            // Did we hit something with an outline?
            if(hit.gameObejct.TryGetComponent<Outline>(out currentSelected))
            {
                // If so enable it
                // it is already automatically stored as current selection
                currentSelected.enabled = true;          
            }
            // otherwise the current selection will be set to null automatically
        }
        // otherwise nothing to do since we still hit the same object
    }
    else // not hitting anything
    {
        // Do we still have something selected?
        if(currentSelected) 
        {
            // Then disable it
            currentSelected.enabled = false;
        }
        // And forget the reference
        currentSelected = null;
    }

    // If we have a current selection and click
    if (currentSelected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Clicked on {currentSelected.name}", this);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: When I put that code into the script, it just give me errors on "gameObject". The suggestion to fix it is to put an else statement right after ` if (currentSelected && currentSelected.gameObject != hit.gameObject) ` and that doesn't even fix anything. Any help on this?

Comment: Thank you for this! The thing about doing raycast twice helped to clean the code up a bit, but it still took way longer for me to properly get it working, but I did. Also I did end up using two scripts for it since I had to, one had to be on the camera and the other had to be on the objects. Also I can't put the code its too long rip.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the end! For anyone reading this later that wants it, here's the finished code.
Raycast Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class CastingToObject : MonoBehaviour
{

public static string selectedObject;
public string internalObject;
public RaycastHit theObject;
public LayerMask layerMask;
public bool rayObjectHit;


void Start()
{
    internalObject = "null";
}
// Store the current selected outline reference
Outline currentSelected;
void Update()
{
    // Script for highlighting object


    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out theObject, layerMask))
    {
        selectedObject = theObject.transform.gameObject.name;
        internalObject = theObject.transform.gameObject.name;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedObject = null;
        internalObject = "null";
    }
        if (selectedObject != null)
    {
        // Script for clicking object
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log(theObject.transform.gameObject.name);
        }

        
    }
    
}
}
```

Script that enables/disables another one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SelectedFlash : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject highlightObject;
public Outline outlineScript;
public bool lookingAtObject = false;
public GameObject noneObject;
private CastingToObject castingToObjectScript;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    noneObject = GameObject.Find("none");
    castingToObjectScript = GetComponent<CastingToObject>();
    lookingAtObject = false;
    outlineScript = GetComponent<Outline>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    highlightObject = GameObject.Find(CastingToObject.selectedObject);
        
    if (highlightObject == null) //Nothing selected
    {
        lookingAtObject = false;
        GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = false;
        highlightObject = noneObject;
        
    }
    if (highlightObject != null) //Something selected
    {
        lookingAtObject = true;
        highlightObject.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = true;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You would still be way better using only one script for this .. polling the state in `Update` every frame is way worse than working event based. Also using `Find` is extremely expensive and makes no sense at all for you ... You already **have** the reference to `CastingToObject.selectedObject` so why would you use the expensive `Find` just to optain the same reference or - in bad cases where the names are equal for multiple objects - a wrong object ...